# how to make changes these codes to refer to constants like below either from a Class (with static int) or Enum

Tags: java, enums

```
if (requestDTO.getType() != 6 && requestDTO.getType() != 7){
}
```

I have to make constants either static or enum, and I want to make it enum. 
How can I use enum in this method?

There are 1 to 7 types and I need a enum classs

Comment: Hint: try dropping requirements+code if you want to avoid downvotes. We are not here to do all your work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public enum DtoType{

    TYPE1(1), TYPE2(2),... TYPE7(7)

    private final String value;

    DtoType(String value){
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
```

Then

```
if (requestDTO.getType() != DtoType.TYPE6.getValue() && requestDTO.getType() != DtoType.TYPE7.getValue()){}
```

Or even easier if you don't need the numbers

```
public enum DtoType{

    TYPE1, TYPE2,... TYPE7

}
```

Then

```
if (requestDTO.getType() != DtoType.TYPE6 && requestDTO.getType() != DtoType.TYPE7){}
```

Answer (score 1):

With enums you can do something like

```
enum MyConstants { 
    ONE(1),
    TWO(2), 
    THREE(3), 
    FOUR(4),
    FIVE(5),
    SIX(6),
    SEVEN(7);
    private final int val;
    MyConstants(int val){ 
        this.val= val;
    }
    public int getIntValue(){
        return val;
    }
};
```

Now, you would simply use the enum as

```
if (requestDTO.getType() != MyConstants.SIX && requestDTO.getType() != MyConstants.SEVEN)
```

This example assumes that getType retuns a MyConstants object.